Why is a React Native app not built for iOS?
npx react-native run ios 

error: invalid value 'c++20' in '-std=c++20'
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folder/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/YGValue.o /Users/user/Desktop/folder/projectfolder/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGValue.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folder/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/event.o /Users/user/Desktop/folder/projectfolder/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/event/event.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/folder/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Yoga.o /Users/user/Desktop/folder/projectfolder/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
npx react-native info 

info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: macOS 10.15.7
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570R CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 254.02 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell:
version: 3.2.57
path: /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node:
version: 20.12.1
path: /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn:
version: 1.22.22
path: /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm:
version: 10.5.0
path: /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman:
version: 2023.11.13.00
path: /opt/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods:
version: 1.15.2
path: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms:
- iOS 14.4
- DriverKit 20.2
- macOS 11.1
- tvOS 14.3
- watchOS 7.2
Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: Not Found
Xcode:
version: 12.4/12D4e
path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: Not Found
Ruby:
version: 3.3.0
path: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.3.0/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
"@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
react: Not Found
react-native: Not Found
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
"react-native": Not Found
Android:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
hermesEnabled: true
newArchEnabled: false
npx react-native doctor 

⠏ Running diagnostics.../bin/sh: adb: command not found
Common
✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode
✓ Metro - Required for bundling the JavaScript code
Android
✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
✖ JDK - Required to compile Java code

Version found: N/A
Version supported: >= 17 <= 20
✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✖ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
Versions found: N/A
Version supported: 34.0.0

iOS
✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
✓ Ruby - Required for installing iOS dependencies
✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
● ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
✓ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment
Errors:   5
Warnings: 1
I changed C++ Language Dialect on Yoga pod build settings to gnu++14

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
